# cv::floodFill return value

Tags: c++, opencv

Apparently `cv::floodFill` has an `int` return value, however I can't find anywhere documented what it is supposed to be.

What I'm hoping is that it will be the number of pixels "reached" by the flood-fill function, but is it guaranteed to be that?

```
CV_EXPORTS_W int floodFill( InputOutputArray image, InputOutputArray mask,
                            Point seedPoint, Scalar newVal, CV_OUT Rect* rect=0,
                            Scalar loDiff = Scalar(), Scalar upDiff = Scalar(),
                            int flags = 4 );
```

Comment: Based on the [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/floodfill.cpp#L618) it appears to be an area, as you expected. Might be worth filing an issue on the OpenCV Github, so that this omission gets fixed.

Comment: you can edit the api docs in the corresponding header file. just make a pull request.

Comment: I genuinely think it's the number of "reached" pixels. Even though in some examples its declared with a variable name `area`, in the examples' prints it appears to be a number of pixels. See [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d17/samples_2cpp_2ffilldemo_8cpp-example.html#a11).